# Spring interceptor add data in the postHandle

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, interceptor

I am building an application using spring boot and AngularJS. I add an interceptor in the java code. The interceptor is to check who is the user and What I want to do is to add the user name in the postHandle, so the view can know the user name for every request.

I know I can add an object in the modelandview. But now I do not want to use jsp and any template engines, and I just want to use client side rendering. Does anyone know what I can do now? What is the normal industry practice for this?

Thanks

Comment: just send a json response, add user name from controller (where the response is generated)

Comment: @benjaminc Thanks for your reply. But in this way, I need to add it for all controller. Is there any way to do it once? Thanks.

Comment: you could send a response header containing user name

Comment: @benjaminc Thanks. I will try this way. Any other suggestions?

Comment: use your interceptor to inject the response header